# Filtering table data based on search keyword using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I want to accomplish one simple thing using jQuery. I want to filter some table data on a page and there is a search box on top of the same page.

On every keystroke, I want to hide each row that does not match the search field. I want to process only client side data. How can I accomplish this?

Can anyone please give some example code of this? Like, how can I grab each keystroke and hide the required elements? I want something like [this.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_localfilter_clean.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onkeydown`, then grab it's `val()`, then find out if what the value `:contains`, matches up against whatever elements your using to compare it against, then `hide()` whatever elements do not match this condition and voila.

**HTML:**

```
<input type = "text" id="theText">
```

**JQuery to get it's current value and display it on the console:**

```
$('#theText').onkeydown(function(){

var x = $('#theText').val();

console.log(x);

});
```

Comment: how can I get the value of what is typed in the search box if I don't have a form? I just have a search box (text box) and I need the value what is typed in that box to do the processing, right? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am using Data Table plug in of jQuery. But, many thanks for your help :) +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little old now, but I've used this plug-in in a project before and it worked great:
https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch